# can't process persistAction.create

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a problem to make simple form web site in jsf.
i use primefaces for button.
when click button, why the program can't do persistAction.create in my code ?

this is my html

```
    <h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit size="100" position="north"/>
        <p:layoutUnit size="300" position="west"/>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form id="frmDaftar">
                <p:panel id="panelList" style="width: 370px" header="Registrasi Mahasiswa Baru">
                    <p:panelGrid  columns="2" style="border: #ffffff"> 
                        <p:outputLabel for="nim" value="NIM"/>
                        <p:inputText id="nim" value="#{mahasiswaController.selected.nim}" title="nim" required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill the blank field"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="nama_lengkap" value="Nama Lengkap"/>
                        <p:inputText id="nama_lengkap" value="#{mahasiswaController.selected.nama}" title="nama" required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill the blank field"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="tempatLahir" value="Tempat Lahir"/>
                        <p:inputText id="tempatLahir" value="#{mahasiswaController.selected.tempatLahir}" title="tempat_lahir" required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill the blank field"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="mask" value="Tanggal Lahir" />
                        <p:calendar id="mask" value="#{mahasiswaController.selected.tanggalLahir}" title="tanggal_lahir" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill the blank field"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="fakultas"  value="Fakultas"/>
                        <p:inputText id="fakultas" value="#{mahasiswaController.selected.fakultas}" title="fakultas" required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill the blank field"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="jurusan" value="Jurusan"/>
                        <p:inputText id="jurusan" value="#{mahasiswaController.selected.jurusan}" title="jurusan" required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill the blank field"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="telepon" value="Telepon"/>
                        <p:inputMask id="telepon" mask="(9999) 9999-9999" value="#{mahasiswaController.selected.telepon}" title="telepon" required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill the blank field"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="alamat" value="Alamat"/>
                        <p:inputTextarea id="alamat" value="#{mahasiswaController.selected.alamat}" title="alamat" required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill the blank field"/>
                        <p:spacer/>
                        <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{mahasiswaController.create()}" process="@this" value="Confirm" update="panelList" validateClient="true"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Clear" update="panelList" actionListener="#{mahasiswaController.create()}"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>  
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

and bean

```
public class MahasiswaController implements Serializable {

@EJB
private com.nop.univ.MahasiswaFacade ejbFacade;
private List<Mahasiswa> items = null;
private Mahasiswa selected;


public MahasiswaController() {
}

public Mahasiswa getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Mahasiswa selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

protected void setEmbeddableKeys() {
}

protected void initializeEmbeddableKey() {
}

private MahasiswaFacade getFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
}

public Mahasiswa prepareCreate() {
    selected = new Mahasiswa();
    initializeEmbeddableKey();
    return selected;
}

Integer nim =0, header =1234;
String tgl;
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

private Integer findNim() {
    try {  
    items = getFacade().findAll();
    tgl = sdf.format(date).replace("/", "");
    tgl = tgl.substring(0, 8);
    nim = items.size();
    nim = Integer.parseInt(tgl) + header + nim;
    items =null;
    return nim;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    return null;
    }
}

private void save() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Data Saved"));
}

public void create() {
    //selected.setNim(findNim());
    persist(PersistAction.CREATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("MahasiswaCreated"));
    save();
    if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
        items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
    }
}

public void update() {
    persist(PersistAction.UPDATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("MahasiswaUpdated"));
}

public void destroy() {
    persist(PersistAction.DELETE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("MahasiswaDeleted"));
    if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
        selected = null; // Remove selection
        items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
    }
}
```

can anyone help me for my problem, beacause when i debug the program actually the program do persistAction.create, but when i check in my table is nothing

Comment: Make your JSF bean `@ViewScoped` and check if the view is updated. Also, make sure you can commit transactions from your application and there's nothing blocking that kind of operations

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your explain. can you make example in code ? thx b4

Comment: Is there no stacktrace? I'd think you need to remove process="@this" on the button to get the values updated in the bean, then it will default to @form

Comment: thank's, but it didn't work. i so confuse, the program running normaly, but the data was nothing. can you give me example like this ? for tag p:commandButton and save through persistAction.CREATE ?

thx